# go test flag: flag provided but not defined

Tags: go

Hi I am using a flag when testing in go:
file_test.go
`var ip = flag.String("ip", "noip", "test")`

I am only using this in one test file. And it works fine when only testing that one test file, but when I run:
`go test ./... -ip 127.0.0.1` alle of the other test file saying: `flag provided but not defined`.

Have you seen this?

Regards

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`flag.Parse()` is being called before your flag is defined.

You have to make sure that all flag definitions happen before calling `flag.Parse()`, usually by defining all flags inside `init()` functions.

Comment: Thanks, it still only works within the same package, but not when running all tests with: ./...

Comment: @ChrisG. if you're testing multiple packages, any flags you provide must be valid in all of them. There's no way around that.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to ignore a test with regexp -run?

Comment: @ChrisG.: ignoring a test won't help. You're telling go to run `go test` on the `./...` wildcard. That's not a single test run, it's testing every matching package in succession. Simply don't use `./...` and test the packages you want to test.

Answer (score 15):

If you've migrated to golang 13, it changed the order of the test initializer,
so it could lead to something like

```
flag provided but not defined: -test.timeout
```

as a possible workaround, you can use

```
var _ = func() bool {
    testing.Init()
    return true
}()
```

that would call test initialization before the application one. More info can be found on the original thread:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859#issuecomment-489889428

Answer (score 4):

I'm very late to the party; but is this broken (again) on Go 1.19.5?

I hit the same errors reported on this thread and the same solution reported above (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859#issuecomment-489889428) fixes it.

I see a call to `flags.Parse()` was added back in `go_test.go` in `v1.18`

https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/f7248f05946c1804b5519d0b3eb0db054dc9c5d6%5E%21/src/cmd/go/go_test.go

I am only just learning Go so it'd be nice to have some verification from people more skilled before I report this elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

do not call flag.Parse() in any init()

Comment: Ok thanks good to know, how would you then test it?

Comment: You want to define the flags before calling them, which you can do in an `init()` as well. However, using init to do things makes testing difficult, and you're better off using a helper function off of main to do this work.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this, when running command via `docker-compose` then you do incorrect quoting. Eg.

```
services:
  app:
    ...
    image: kumina/openvpn-exporter:latest
    command: [  
      "--openvpn.status_paths", "/etc/openvpn_exporter/openvpn-status.log",
      "--openvpn.status_paths /etc/openvpn_exporter/openvpn-status.log",
    ]
```

First is correct, second is wrong, because whole line counted as one parameter. You need to split them by passing two separate strings, like in first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can run flag.Parse() only one time, check if you are calling another code with flag.Parse()