# "flag provided but not defined" error in Go test despite the flag being defined in init()?

Tags: go

This question is similar to [go test flag: flag provided but not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699982/go-test-flag-flag-provided-but-not-defined), but since that question does not contain a minimal example and the answer is quite high-level, I'm asking it again. In a Go module with a `main.go` and a `main_test.go`,

```
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── main_test.go
```

The `main.go` defines a `sayHi` flag:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var sayHi bool

func init() {
    flag.BoolVar(&sayHi, "sayHi", false, "Say hi or not")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    if sayHi {
        fmt.Println("Hi!")
    }
}
```

and the `main_test.go` is just a placeholder test:

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func TestSayHi(t *testing.T) {

}
```

The problem is that if I try to run the tests, I get a "flag provided but not defined" error:

```
> go test ./...
flag provided but not defined: -test.testlogfile
Usage of /var/folders/tp/s7nwwdws1wj0z8s0vftppnnc0000gn/T/go-build952058535/b001/my-module.test:
  -sayHi
        Say hi or not
FAIL    github.com/kurtpeek/my-module   0.192s
FAIL
```

From the answer of the aforementioned question,

> You have to make sure that all flag definitions happen before calling `flag.Parse()`, usually by defining all flags inside `init()` functions.

I don't see how that is not being done here?

Comment: Why are you parsing in `init()` instead of in `main()`?

Answer (score 2):

Update as of May 2022 - NOT fixed

So far the recommended approach is to move flag initalisation outside of `init()` (so stupid, I know!)

So I did that:

- moving the code for flag handling to its own function,
- and then calling that function at the top of `main()`

and my tests stopped complaining.

```golang
func initParseCommandLineFlags() {
   // do your flag thing here
}

func main() {
    initParseCommandLineFlags()
    ...
}
```

**NOTE**: A huge down side was that I had to move *all* of my initialisation out of `init()` into other setup functions, because my program startup can be modified by command line switches.

So I don't have `init` anymore :(

Reference: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46869#issuecomment-865695953

Answer (score 0):

Create test binary with following command and then execute it with your argument.

```
> go test -c -o test
./test --sayHi=true
PASS
```

go test command does not pass along the arguments to underlying tests.